# Git & Github: El commit por SSH aparece hecho por otra cuenta

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Estoy trabajando los commits mediante llaves SSH, el proceso que hago para identificarme es el siguiente:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/Desktop/ssh/Github/UsuarioA  <--- Llave privada
```

Incluso si ejecuto el comando

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Me aparece que me identifiqué como el usuario A: *Hi **UsuarioA**! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.*

¡Pero al hacer commits me aparece que los hizo el **UsuarioB**!

Lo que más se me hace extraño es que ya eliminé las llaves del UsuarioB, no existen. Y el repositorio es privado y el UsuarioB no tiene permiso de acceso a ese repositorio. No entiendo qué está pasando, pues no hay *warnings* ni errores, ¿Alguna idea de lo que está pasando?

**Nota:** Uso GitBash para ello y trabajo con Windows

Imagen del problema:

[image: Captura de Github]

Comment: Si usas github, tienes creada una key alli? : https://gyazo.com/f5f56086a301edfdf9ed4bee385eb5b4

Comment: Bueno, pues tengo la llave pública subida en github y agrego la llave privada después del `$eval()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné con ayuda de [este blog](https://dev.to/web3coach/how-to-configure-a-local-git-repository-to-use-a-specific-ssh-key-4aml), el cual nos indica cómo configurar el .git/config para que te reconozca la llave ssh específica.

Quedando la configuración del .git/config parecida a esta:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/Desktop/ssh/Github/UsuarioA"
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:UsuarioA/Repositorio.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
[user]
    name = UsuarioA
    email = UsuarioA@correo.ejemplo.com
```

De la configuración adicional que agregué fue todo **[user]** y **[core].sshCommand**

Comment: Bien que lo hayas solucionado. En todo caso, una explicación sencilla: quien va a quedar como el autor de los commits **no es** quien hace el push al repositorio. Yo podría empujar a un repositorio nuevo todo el contenido de master de linux y eso no va a hacer que yo de pronto me convierta en el autor de linux. Las revisiones van a seguir teniendo los mismos autores de cuando se crearon las revisiones.

Comment: Pero si hacía el add, el commit y el push después de identificarme con la llave SSH, ¿Por qué me aparecía hecha por otra cuenta?

Comment: La llave ssh no tiene relación con el usuario que queda en el commit. Lo que queda en el commit es lo que está configurado en `user.name` y `user.email`